# What is best approach to join data in spark streaming application?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

Question : **Essentially it means , rather than running a join of C* table for each streaming records , is there anyway to run a join for each micro-batch ( micro-batching ) of records in spark streaming ?**

We are almost finalized to use spark-sql 2.4.x version , datastax-spark-cassandra-connector for  Cassandra-3.x version.

But have one fundamental question regarding the efficiency in the below scenario.

For the streaming data records(i.e. streamingDataSet ) , I need to look up for existing records( i.e. cassandraDataset) from Cassandra(C*) table.

i.e.

```
Dataset<Row> streamingDataSet = //kafka read dataset

Dataset<Row> cassandraDataset= //loaded from C* table those records loaded earlier from above.
```

To look up data i need to join above datasets

i.e.

```
Dataset<Row> joinDataSet = cassandraDataset.join(cassandraDataset).where(//somelogic)
```

process further the joinDataSet to implement the business logic ...

> In the above scenario, my understanding is ,for each record received
>   from kafka stream it would query the C* table i.e. data base call.
>
> Does not it take huge time and network bandwidth if C* table consists
>   billions of records? What should be the approach/procedure to be
>   followed to improve look up C* table ?
>
> What is the best solution in this scenario ? I CAN NOT load once from
>   C* table and look up as the data keep on adding to C* table ... i.e.
>   new look ups might need newly persisted data.

How to handle this kind of scenario? any advices plzz..

Comment: are you using OSS Cassandra or DataStax Enterprise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Apache Cassandra, then you have only one possibility for effective join with data in Cassandra - via [RDD API's `joinWithCassandraTable`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable). The open source version of the Spark Cassandra Connector (SCC) supports only it, while in version for DSE, there is a code that allows to perform effective join against Cassandra also for Spark SQL - so-called [DSE Direct Join](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2018/05/23/DSEDirectJoin/). If you'll use `join` in Spark SQL against Cassandra table, Spark will need to read all data from Cassandra, and then perform join - that's very slow.

I don't have an example for OSS SCC for doing the join for Spark Structured Streaming, but I have some examples for "normal" join, like [this](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/spark/JoinTestsRDD.java):

```java
CassandraJavaPairRDD<Tuple1<Integer>, Tuple2<Integer, String>> joinedRDD =
     trdd.joinWithCassandraTable("test", "jtest",
     someColumns("id", "v"), someColumns("id"),
     mapRowToTuple(Integer.class, String.class), mapTupleToRow(Integer.class));
```

Comment: yes - `joinWithCassandraTables` takes records from microbatch & uses primary key from that records to fetch actual records from Cassandra